Mysterious 518 Messages in iCloud: Hidden Second Trash or Bug?
I've noticed a peculiar issue with my iCloud account. Despite regularly deleting messages and emptying the trash, I consistently have 518 messages in iCloud that occupy space but aren't visible anywhere in my account. Here's what I've observed:

This number (518) remains constant month after month.
I've tried deleting all messages and emptying the trash.
I changed the setting from "Keep for 30 days" to "Keep for 1 year" to force the old deletion pop-up.
I've monitored the number of messages for several months, always returning to 518.

My theory is that there might be a second, hidden trash in iCloud for data recovery after deleting from the system trash. The process would be:
App > Trash > iCloud (hidden) > Permanent deletion after 30 days
Has anyone else experienced this? Do you know how to reset this to zero? Would disabling Messages in iCloud completely or using a web option help?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to Ask Different. I have the impression you are talking about iMessage messages, but your question is tagged with both "mail.app" and "messages", what are those 518 messages, email messages or iMessage messages? Where do you see the number "518"? Do you use a Mac or an iPhone/iPad? Could you add OS version and device model to your post?
